# Changing OSX Mavericks Server to default to personal website rather than welcome page

Tags: macos, osx-server

I've looked at every option in OSX Server for Mavericks but I don't see anything that allows me to default to my website rather than the "Welcome to Server" page. I have a DNS set up through Godaddy. I had no issues before I installed OSX server. I tried using an alias but that still requires that the URL I provide people has to include that alias. Not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this within Mavericks Server is to adjust the Server Website Preferences to the folder you are locating your HTML pages.

Here's how to do it:

1. Open up the Server application, and select on Websites, under
   Services.
2. Double click on "Server Website" under Websites.
3. Next to the option titled "Store Site Files In:", click the text
   box, select "Other...", navigate to the location where your website
   is stored, and select its top level folder.
4. Click the "OK" button

That should be all. If networking/DNS/Port Forwarding are properly set, you should now be able to load your site.